# compiling issue with atom and f#

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

hey guys I'm trying to compile this function called 2v2 that multiplies any number times 2. I'm doing it using Atom with ionide but when i run it using the f# interactive, it gives me this error saying that it doesn't see the rest of the function. Any suggestions?

```
let times 2v2 n =
 let p = 2 in
 n*2;;
times 2v2 10;;



let times 2v2 n =;;
let times 2v2 n =;;
----------^^^
/stdin(4,11): error FS1156: This is not a valid numeric literal. Sample formats include 4, 0x4, 0b0100, 4L, 4UL, 4u, 4s, 4us, 4y, 4uy, 4.0, 4.0f, 4I.
```

Comment: Where did you get this code with `2v2`? What is `2v2` suppose to be, a variable, a constant? Also what is `let p = 2` used for? If you want to learn F# and have an Windows OS then use [Visual Studio Community Edition 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) which is free.

Comment: That's not an Ionide issue - as it says, `2v2` is simply not a valid thing to write. It starts with a digit, so the compiler tries to interpret it as a number, but it is not a valid number of any type. What are you trying to do? (Actually, yes, that whole bit of code is quite odd.)

Comment: Voting to close as question is off topic - I can't figure out what you want;your title is about a text editor and you ask for suggestions, but give us an error and no idea of what you have tried.

Comment: Have you looked at the [F# info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/info)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a function called `times 2v2` that multiplies its parameter with 2. Since the name of your function contains a space, you have to enclose it with double backticks. For example:

```
let ``times 2v2`` n = 2 * n
```

And also use these when calling the function:

```
``times 2v2`` 10
```

Without double backticks, identifiers must not begin with numbers or contain spaces. Otherwise, the compiler would have a hard time figuring out whether it's dealing with one or multiple identifiers.

A minimalist way to make the question's code valid would be to remove the space between `times` and `2v2`. The variable `p` would serve no purpose though.